# Evaluating the trace of two discrete Sine and Cosine transforms

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, trigonometric-series

We recall that discrete Cosine transform of type 5 and discrete Sine transform of type 8 are given as follows:
$$C_5=\left(\cos kl\frac{\pi}{n-\frac{1}{2}}\right)_{0\leq k,l\leq n-1}~,~S_8=\left(\sin (k+\frac12)(l+\frac12)\frac{\pi}{n-\frac{1}{2}}\right)_{0\leq k,l\leq n-1}$$

Any suggestion to compute the trace of these two transforms?

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\frac{4k^2\pi}{2n-1} \tag1\\[6pt]
&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin\frac{(2k+1)^2\pi}{2(2n-1)} \tag2 
\end{align}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: very well-known?

Comment: "very well-known"?  Please explain.

Comment: Where did these come from?

Comment: @ 
David G. Stork and @ 
person, I added some more points.

Comment: Consider how the first sum relates to the quadratic Gauss sum
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{2 n - 2}
 \exp \left( 2 \pi i \frac {2 k^2} {2 n - 1} \right).$$
For the second sum, take $k' = k + n$ to eliminate the linear term, then compare the result to
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{2 n - 2}
 \exp \left( 2 \pi i \frac {k^2} {2 n - 1} \right).$$

Comment: @Maxim As for the first one, we have to compute $\sum_{k=n}^{2n-2}\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{2k^2}{2n-1} \right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{2(k+n)^2}{2n-1} \right)$ which is as difficult as the main sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\frac{4k^2\pi}{2n-1}$!

Comment: The closest I've found is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin(\frac{2\pi k^2}{n}) = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\left( 1 + \cos(\frac{n\pi}{2}) - \sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}) \right)$ in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik 1.344.2 (and a similar one for summing $\cos$ terms in 1.344.3). See page 86 (numbered 37) of [this pdf version](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf).

Comment: @  Peter,   It is a great reference.  Thanks a lot.